# Set datagrid cell combo box backgroud in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have datagrid that display customer data. some columns has combo box. on row validation error i would like to change the combo box background to red. How do i do it?
I have tried setting new data template on ROW loaded event but it did not work. I also tried to to modify the existing template but I get error that it is sealed and can not be modified.

Update1: 
I also tried to use setter like one in here 
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/gridview/rowloaded-event-to-change-font-style.aspx

still no result.

Update2:
I am setting the data template in code behind. Like teh following

```
 Private Sub SetDataTemplate(e As GridViewAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs, currentCompPropdefinition As ComponentPropertyDefinition)
    Dim celltemplate = Nothing
    If currentCompPropdefinition.Type = GetType(Boolean) OrElse currentCompPropdefinition.ValidValues IsNot Nothing Then
        If currentCompPropdefinition.Type = GetType(Boolean) Then
            celltemplate = New FrameworkElementFactory(GetType(CheckBox))
            celltemplate.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, New Binding(e.Column.Header))
        ElseIf currentCompPropdefinition.ValidValues IsNot Nothing AndAlso currentCompPropdefinition.ValidValues.Count <> 0 Then
            celltemplate = New FrameworkElementFactory(GetType(Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadComboBox))
            celltemplate.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, New Binding() With {.Source = currentCompPropdefinition.ValidValues})
            celltemplate.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, New Binding(e.Column.Header))
            celltemplate.SetValue(ComboBox.BackgroundProperty, FindResource("LightBG")) '(ComboBox.BackgroundProperty, )
        End If
        Dim dataTemplate As New DataTemplate() With {.VisualTree = celltemplate}

        dataTemplate.Seal()
        e.Column.CellTemplate = dataTemplate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show your `Datatemplate` xaml code?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I have updated the post. please take a look.